# can any body please tell me how to create like this type of layout

Tags: android

[image]

finding too much examples but cant find this layout any example and please tell me the layout name

i am trying to take an Imageview but still it will not works for me because imageview can not work like that

Answer (score 2):

Use Linear Layout, and imageView inside it.
Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/YourImage">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not complicated, just create with some imaging software (Photoshop, gimp, paint .net etc. ) a rectangle which looks like like this:

[image]

and just set the rest of the screen to be the same color as the white part.